# how to monitor any changes from items on azure devops and e-mail it

Tags: azure-devops

Basically I need to track any changes done by others in term of work items.
Then send e-mail or display on Board according different changes they made.

Comment: I think I need to gather all changes in history and discussion srctor and then classified them if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can new subscription in Notification and then choose `A work item is changed` option.

[image]

Then edit subscription, add the Filter criteria you want to get notification.

[image]